# sapply function(x) where x is subsetted argument

Tags: r, sapply

So, I want to generate a new vector from the information in two existing ones (numerical), one which sets the id for the participant, the other indicating the observation number. Each paticipant has been observed different times.

Now, the new vector should should state: 0 when obs_no=1; 1 when obs_no=last observation for that id; NA for cases in between.

```
id   obs_no   new_vector
1    1        0
1    2        NA
1    3        NA
1    4        NA
1    5        1
2    1        0
2    2        1
3    1        0
3    2        NA
3    3        1
```

I figure I could do this separatly for every id using code like this

```
new_vector <- c(0, rep(NA, times=length(obs_no[id==1])-2), 1)
```

Or I guess just using max() but it wouldn't make any difference.

But adding each participant manually is really inconvenient since I have a lot of cases. I can't figure out how to make a generic function. I tried to define a function(x) using sapply but cant get it to work since x is positioned within subsetting brackets.

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ave` to the rescue:

```
dat$newvar <- NA
dat$newvar <- with(dat,
  ave(newvar, id, FUN=function(x) replace(x, c(length(x),1), c(1,0)) ) 
)
```

Or use a bit of `duplicated()` fun:

```
dat$newvar <- NA
dat$newvar[!duplicated(dat$id, fromLast=TRUE)] <- 1
dat$newvar[!duplicated(dat$id)] <- 0
```

Both giving:

```
#   id obs_no new_vector newvar
#1   1      1          0      0
#2   1      2         NA     NA
#3   1      3         NA     NA
#4   1      4         NA     NA
#5   1      5          1      1
#6   2      1          0      0
#7   2      2          1      1
#8   3      1          0      0
#9   3      2         NA     NA
#10  3      3          1      1
```

Comment: If there is only one observation for a group, any idea what should be the value?

Comment: Oh yeah that's right, if there is only one observation the value should be 0! The "duplicated" solution still works if I swap the order of second and third line though! Thank you!

Comment: @andreasgoteson - I've swapped the orders around to account for this - the `ave` version should work too now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with `dplyr`

```
str <- "
id   obs_no   new_vector
1    1        0
1    2        NA
1    3        NA
1    4        NA
1    5        1
2    1        0
2    2        1
3    1        0
3    2        NA
3    3        1
"

dt <- read.table(textConnection(str), header = T)

library(dplyr)

dt %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(newvar = if_else(obs_no==1,0L,if_else(obs_no==max(obs_no),1L,as.integer(NA))))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df1)[, .I[seq_len(.N) %in% c(1, .N)], id]$V1
df1[i1, newvar := c(0, 1)]
df1
#     id obs_no new_vector newvar
# 1:  1      1          0      0
# 2:  1      2         NA     NA
# 3:  1      3         NA     NA
# 4:  1      4         NA     NA
# 5:  1      5          1      1
# 6:  2      1          0      0
# 7:  2      2          1      1
# 8:  3      1          0      0
# 9:  3      2         NA     NA
#10:  3      3          1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split`:

```
result = lapply(split(obs_no, id), function (x) c(0, rep(NA, length(x) - 2), 1))
```

This gives you a list of vectors. You can paste them back together like this:

```
do.call(c, result)
```

Comment: Smart solution, thank you! Works well for the example given but somehow causes an error with original data. "Invalid 'times' argument"

Comment: @andreasgoteson You need to provide more information then. Especially since the other solutions go quite a detour in order to solve the problem. I’d guess that there are some of your IDs that only have a single value to them? What do you want to assign in those cases?

Comment: As comments above - single value cases should be assigned value 0. Sorry I forgot to state that first. But above solutions solved my problem, despite the detour.